# Copying values of array

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I'm trying to copy the value of pos even indexed value to words, an array.
And I am getting a nullpointerexpection in this code

```
    for (String a : token)
    {
        temp = temp + " " + a;
        pos = a.split("[_\\s]+");

    }
    for (int i=0;i<pos.length;i=i+2)
    {
        int c=0;
        words[c]=pos[i]; //in this line
        c++;
    }
```

Comment: On which line? It looks like your second loop is supposed to be nested...

Comment: Where is your 'words' array allocated?

Comment: `words` is indeed the prime suspect. `c` is a primitive, so it can't be null. `pos` is the result of a String `split` call. That leaves `words`.

Answer (score 1):

Given the NullPointerException, it is very likely that `words` is null. When you allocate it, you do need to make sure it is big enough, or you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `words` array has been initialized with at least as many positions as the size of `pos.length` for example if you do not have the words array initialized with 7 spots for characters and `pos.length == 8` then its going to point to a position in the `words` array that doesn't exist. Maybe try initializing the `words` array with more memory locations than you need? Also make sure you are taking into account the steps of 2 in the second for loop.

edit:
maybe try initializing the array with values?